# 100A main breaker trips when using 60A heater

Tags: electrical-panel

My heater has a 60A/10 ka breaker inside of it, but the panel breaker is only 50A/10ka. The main breaker is 100A. Service is 240v.

Do I need to upgrade the service panel to solve this issue?

Comment: And the 100A breaker is what trips? Yes, you'd need a panel upgrade. Depending on your aptitude you may be able to do that yourself.

Comment: Thank you and also I have an outside main breaker of 100 amps I'm assuming this needs to be changed out to 200 amps as well

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: United States..

Comment: It could be that there is a single loose lug causing this problem.  It could also be possible to just replace the main breaker without complete upgrade.

Comment: breakers are only rated to fault a few times before going out of spec, which is likely whats happened here. Replace the breaker and if the problem persists look into a service upgrade.

Comment: Is the main breaker a GFCI?  What is the nameplate amp rating of the heater? Did they have any instructions about what size of wire and breaker to use with it?   How fast is is tripping, instantly or in a 10 seconds?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the 100-Amp main is tripping, supplying a load of about 45-Amps through a 60 & 50-Amp breakers doesn't really say anything other than the 100-Amp breaker has failed and conceivably needs to be change.  However, given that you have a 45-Amp load on a heater, which we consider to be a continuous load, you are very smart to upgrade to 200-Amp capacity.  This higher capacity needs to go all the way to the weather head.

Comment: Where did 45 come from?

Comment: Thank you, for the compliment and all of you for the excellent advice we almost scrapped the whole place and started over.

Comment: @JPhi1618;  10KW divided the driving voltage, 240 gives us the current draw; 40 to 45-Amps.